# overall vs in general

Tags: comparison

Please take a look at these two sentences:

- 1. This medicine can help your health in general.
- 2. This medicine can help your health overall.

From 1., I can know that my health can improve in most parts. But, I can't say the same for 2..

I checked "overall", which can mean "general", or "all things and circumstance considered". In view of this, 2. seems very ambiguous.

Could anyone help explain?

Thank you very much for your time,

Leon

Comment: "This medicine can help/improve your general health" might be better than either, in context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both meanings are very very similar, to the point where I'm having a hard time saying there is even a difference.

Perhaps I could say: **in general** implies a benefit to two or more functions in your body, such as the digestive and cardiovascular systems (for example); **overall** implies a more nebulous benefit to your general well-being and how you subjectively *feel* (more energy, less pain, etc).

But that is not a very precise or clear distinction, and really I would treat the two phrases as identical unless there was some clarifying or more technical context.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight nuance of meaning here.

overall - taken as a whole, all parts, in all;

in general - as a whole;

Again, this is a nicety for me. And as we are talking about a medicine and its positive effect for health, I'd just as soon use "overall."